# Dataframe subsetting by list, not recognising "NA" values

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have the following issue: I import data from a csv. The imported csv looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c("K","M",NA,NA,"K"))
```

Where K denotes 1 000 and M 1 000 000. I would like to create a new column with dplyr so that I use a list to subset K and M and multiply with values in x column

```
sul <- c("K"=1000, "M"=1000000, "NA"=1)
```

So using dplyr:

```
df %>% mutate(result=x * sul[y])
```

My problem is though, that  that results from importing data from a csv are not being recognized in `sul[y]` and I get either NA or NULL.  Have you an idea how to solve this problem in an elegant way? Is there a better way then running:

`df$y[is.na(df&y)]<-1`

Thanks a lot!

p.s. subsetting by a list is chosen instead of for-loop to increase the speed of processing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to replace `NA` with 'Other' and then do

```
 sul <- c(K=1000, M=1000000, Other=1)
 df %>%
    mutate(y1 = replace(as.character(y), is.na(y), "Other"),
           result = x*sul[y1]) %>%
    select(-y1)
#  x    y  result
#1 1    K    1000
#2 2    M 2000000
#3 3 <NA>       3
#4 4 <NA>       4
#5 5    K    5000
```

---

The 'NA' in `sul` is a character string and not a real `NA`.  So, if we are using the 'sul' from OP's post, `replace` the 'NA' in 'y' to `"NA"`

```
df %>%
      mutate(result = x*sul[replace(as.character(y), is.na(y), "NA")])
```